# Pictures won't display in media library and also won't show preview when selected

Tags: media, media-library, headers, cache, thumbnails

I have done the plug in, check permissions (upload folder which contains files for the media contents is 755), clearing cache (there was none, apparently), disable any extra plug-ins, check and uncheck things, nothing. I did upload everything thru wordpress.

I checked bluehost server status, and it is up. even for my particular username. On my phone, if i go to media (on wordpress app) the images are grey and no preview. If i click on them, it says "There was a problem loading the media item." yes, i refreshed.

Please help.

My header slider image won't appear on the website (even in the customize on the side), and when I click to change photo, the media library is all gray boxes again.

Comment: Have you installed any caching plugins? What does your host say about it?

Comment: You could enable wordpress debugging mode to find the error. Add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to your `wp-config.php` file, and check your media library page for errors.

Comment: i have WP super cache and Force Regenerate Thumbnails. I got those for troubleshooting as i said above.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it. It was with a, surprisingly enough, a recommended plugin. Ans some permissions. I contacted my server and they were able to overwrite it. Thank you!

Comment: Which plugin? Which permissions? Can you please update your answer and explain how **exactly** you solved your problem?